# how do i catch SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error python?

Tags: python, ssl, exception, ssl-certificate, urllib3

I am using urllib3.PoolManager to make http requests. And in some part of my code I use this code to make a request

```
resp = h.request(self.method, self.url, body=body, headers=headers, timeout=TIMEOUT, retries=retries)
```

and I get the error SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED. Below is the full stack trace.

```
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 69, in request
    **urlopen_kw)

  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 90, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)

  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 248, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)

  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 621, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)

[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
```

The error is expected. But the problem is I cannot catch the error in try except block.

I tried to use

```
 except ssl.SSLError:
```

but that does not catch this error.
I also tried ssl.CertificateError but no results.
I can catch it by using the Exception class but I need to catch the specific errors and handle them differently. Can someone please find me a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. The exception class that was being raised is **urllib3.exceptions.SSLError**.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can catch SSL Errors using `requests.exceptions.SSLError`

```
import requests, traceback

try:
    r = requests.get('https://domain.tld')
except (requests.exceptions.SSLError):
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the specific type of any exception, you can use `type()`

```
import requests

try:
    r = requests.get('https://domain.tld')
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))
```

Output:

```
<class 'requests.exceptions.ConnectionError'>
```

Which leads us to:

```
import requests

try:
    r = requests.get('https://domain.tld')
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    print("Caught correctly")
```

Output:

```
Caught correctly
```